# Journalctl spamming pcieport 0000:00:1d.2: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:05:00.0

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-kernel, pci

After checking journalctl logs, I keep getting spammed with this error:

```
Aug 05 21:39:08 archlinux kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.2: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:05:00.0
Aug 05 21:39:08 archlinux kernel: rtw_8822be 0000:05:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 05 21:39:08 archlinux kernel: rtw_8822be 0000:05:00.0:   device [10ec:b822] error status/mask=00000001/00006000
Aug 05 21:39:08 archlinux kernel: rtw_8822be 0000:05:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Aug 05 21:39:08 archlinux kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.2: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:05:00.0
Aug 05 21:39:08 archlinux kernel: rtw_8822be 0000:05:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 05 21:39:08 archlinux kernel: rtw_8822be 0000:05:00.0:   device [10ec:b822] error status/mask=00000001/00006000
Aug 05 21:39:08 archlinux kernel: rtw_8822be 0000:05:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
```

System specs:

`````
-`                    ouxyre@archlinux 
                  .o+`                   ---------------- 
                 `ooo/                   OS: Arch Linux x86_64 
                `+oooo:                  Host: 20KN003XUS ThinkPad  
               `+oooooo:                 Kernel: 6.4.7-arch1-2 
               -+oooooo+:                Uptime: 2 days, 16 hours,  
             `/:-:++oooo+:               Packages: 815 (pacman) 
            `/++++/+++++++:              Shell: bash 5.1.16 
           `/++++++++++++++:             Resolution: 1920x1080 
          `/+++ooooooooooooo/`           WM: bspwm 
         ./ooosssso++osssssso+`          Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
        .oossssso-````/ossssss+`         Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
       -osssssso.      :ssssssso.        Terminal: kitty 
      :osssssss/        osssso+++.       CPU: Intel i5-8250U (8) @  
     /ossssssss/        +ssssooo/-       GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 62 
   `/ossssso+/:-        -:/+osssso+-     Memory: 8256MiB / 15759MiB 
  `+sso+:-`                 `.-/+oso:
 `++:.                           `-/+/                           
 .`                                 `/
`````

Comment: Please provide the output of lspci -vv